# Como previnir download e impressão de PDF no browser?

Tags: html5

Como previnir o download e a impressão de um arquivo PDF que está sendo exibido no browser?

Gostaria de permitir somente a visualização do arquivo!

Comment: Veja essa lista de opções, as vezes alguma te serve. Mas parece que o mais comum é transformar o PDF em JPG https://www.google.com.br/search?q=how+to+prevent+downloading+pdf+site:stackoverflow.com&newwindow=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi90pjkqN_ZAhWGx5AKHehTB1gQrQIINCgDMAA&biw=1280&bih=893

Comment: É o caso do leite derramado, uma vez exposto ao client, o conteúdo "pertence" a ele... Pode até investir em esforços para dificultar as ações, mas não tem como impedir.